# Translation of "хотя сам он при этом и потерял целый год"

Tags: перевод

> хотя сам он при этом и потерял целый год.

I need a little help witn this clause.
I kinda know what each word means but I dont know how they fit together.

Does this clause mean,

> Although(even if) he had to waste the entire year.

It is from The Alchemist by Paulo Coelho.
The English version is

> the fact that the two hours had stretched into an entire year didn't matter

Comment: Именно это и значит. "Хотя... потерял целый год" - это основная повествовательная часть. Любое из слов "сам он при этом и..." можно пропустить - смысл от этого не изменится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Russian version translates like this:

```
... хотя сам он при зтом и потерял целый год.

... despite he actually wasted/lost a whole year at that.
```

That is different from what the English version literally means (which expresses how much time it took him to do something mentioned earlier rather than 'wasting his time' as in Russian version):

```
...the fact that the two hours had stretched into an entire year didn't matter.

... то, что те два часа растянулись на целый год, не имело значения.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
          [хотя] сам он при этом и потерял целый год
             \\
 [хотя это и не имеет значения] = although it didn't matter


          хотя сам он [при этом] и потерял целый год
                          \\
               [о том, что сказано ранее] = as he had said before
               [учитывая сказанное ранее]
```

--

```
(Хотя это и не имеет значения, что) сам он, (учитывая сказанное про то, что  
путь стал короче) и потерял целый год

=

Хотя сам он при этом и потерял целый год
```